# Why the main form disappears?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On a form a long running task is started by clicking on a button. The task runs on a separate worker thread and I display another form with a progress bar on it while the task is running.

When the task finished or got cancelled otherwise, the form displaying the progress bar gets closed. Dummy code could look like this:

```
task.DoWorkAsync();
progressBar.Show(parent);
```

And when the task finished

```
progressBar.Close();
```

But sometimes exact in the moment that the form displaying the progress bar gets closed, the main form goes to background. To be more precisely, what I have to do to reproduce the issue:

- start my application
- click on another window (of another application, let's say Excel) to bring it to front
- click on my application window (to bring it to front)
- run the task

Now after the progress bar got closed, my application window disappears behind the other one I brought to front (here Excel) before.

Of course what I have described above is very rough outline of my application. But what I need is to find out why my form disappears behind the one when the progress bar got closed.

Comment: It's strange, but does the thread of the main form stay alive?

Comment: You are doing something to make the main window inaccessible.  You forgot to mention that, but that causes the problem.

Comment: Hi Hans and Fuex, yes, correct. I forgot to mention that. The main UI thread stays alive and the main window is disabled to make it inaccessible. I will try not to disable it and see what will happen then.

Comment: Update: Hans, thanks very much! That is the solution! Without disabling the main window the effect is gone. Looks like a lot of work for us to do!

Answer (score 1):

MainForm

```
ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(this);
progress.Show();
this.Hide();
```

ProgressBar

```
parent.Show();
progress.Hide();
```

Alternatively, you could use `ShowDialog()`, which will keep the main form open but inaccessable until the progress bar form is closed.

Comment: The main UI thread continues processing other messages and so cannot be blocked here. I know that's not good, but it was implemented that way 5 years ago and is difficult to clean at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when you close the `Form` that shows a progress bar the main `Form` goes to the background ?

If so, you probably need to give the focus back to the main form after showing the progress bar form, since it stole the focus.

Here is a stack overflow question that talks about form focus :

[Form lost focus - Basic Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401711/form-lost-focus-basic-question)

Comment: Thanks, but my feeling was that often setting forms TopMost=true makes things even worse than better.